# Misplaced bracket with Hebrew text containing letter, digits and hyphen

Tags: polyglossia, brackets, hebrew, bidi

When displaying a Hebrew text, containing letters, digits, and a hyphen - all of these inside brackets, the ending bracket is misplaced.

MWE (using `XeLaTeX`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew} 
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
% misplaced bracket:
[א 1-2]

% bracket in place:
[א 1 2]
\end{document}
```

The output looks like:

[image: output]

Note:
In older installation this worked well, so this is a relatively newer bug.

Any ideas how to workaround this issue, or where should this be reported? (or maybe it's already reported?)

Comment: The `[` picks up the directionality of the `1-2`. Breaking it with a command like `\selectlangauge{hebrew}` or `\phantom{א}` inserts a space. Typing `\mbox{}` after the `2` (in ltr direction) seems to work (TexLive, xelatex): `[{}mbox\א 1-2]`

Comment: Are you saying that it's not a bug, but a feature?
Anyway, based on your idea, I've wrapped the `]` inside a `\RL{}` : `[א 1-2\RL{]}` , and it works well

Comment: I mean, after the `2` (in rtl direction.)

Comment: I don't know about bug or feature. With font renderers, package enhancements and other things, going on lately, a lot of changes increase the probability of gears not meshing. Anyway, `\RL` is good idea. I couldn't remember the command.

Comment: `unisugar` package might be useful.